# Electronically triggering contact pad buttons on a wired remote with a Raspberry Pi

Tags: switches, raspberry-pi

I would like to control my AC with a Raspberry Pi. My system is similar to [this one](https://www.seeleyinternational.com/artefact/breezair-exq-ezq-exs-evaporative-controllers-manual/), although it is an older model from 2004.

Currently the system has a **wired** controller. There is no bluetooth, wifi, IR or RF. A wireless controller can be [purchased](https://www.ebay.com.au/itm/Breezair-Remote-Control-Horizon-107950-/192324663089) for AUD$500 which would also require a [receiver](https://rockhamptoncoolingsolutions.com.au/products/103587-breezair-rf-receiver) to be purchased separately.

I would like to interface a Raspberry Pi with the current wired controller instead.

I need to understand how to activate the contact pads electronically, but I have very limited knowledge in this area. I'm hoping that based on the images attached below, people are able to help me wire it up.

The controller has six buttons but 12 contact pads - two per button.

I will update this question to be more specific once/if I have details.

[image: Back of Remote]

[image: Front of Remote]

Comment: You are going to need to do some hands on circuit investigation to determine if this is possible.  If once set of those fingers is connected to something identifiably "ground" then you could simulate switch closures with something like NPN transistors having their bases driven via series resistors by the pi.  If not it is likely going to be a *lot* more complicated.  Or maybe you can determine if that RJ-11? jack carries some known signaling scheme

Comment: what is the model of the A/C? .... maybe a service manual can be found

Comment: The keyboard is scanned (you can see the diodes on the rear of the board). So picking up/injecting signals is going to be hard. You'd be better getting yourself a USB numeric keypad to plug in to the Raspberry Pi if you are just trying to re-use the remote: https://www.amazon.com/dp/B01E8TTWZ2/ref=sspa_dk_detail_1 or you could go wireless for the same price. Why tackle projects like this unless you want to put the R'Pi in-between the remote and the air-conditioner ….then you want to analyze the serial connection to the unit and do your injection there.

Comment: @JackCreasey Actually, no. **The keypad is not scanned**.  This is evident for two reasons.  First, all of the button features have their lower half connected to the same pour.   Next, those "diodes" match the holes in the board - what they actually are, are LEDs that shine through the holes to light the buttons.  Each one has its own series resistor.

Comment: @ChrisStratton You may well be right. However it would still seem more sensible to capture the serial control protocol, than inject button pushes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the annotated picture below I think we can all agree that all of the button finger contact pads share a common connection with each other (yellow lines) which are likely to all connect to the GND or the VDD of the control circuit. You will have to use a digital meter to probe the circuit to measure voltages and figure out what this common connection is.

The next observation is that each side by side pair of the contact finger pads are tied together on the other side (added blue lines). This is most likely to be done to provide for redundancy and can be confirmed if the remote just has six user button functions instead of twelve functions. All evidence seems to indicate 6 functions.

The next key thing that you will have to do is to determine if it is even safe to hack this wired remote. Being that the remote wires into the guts of the A/C unit it is going to be difficult to figure out if the "GND" of the remote would be safe to wire up to the externally powered Raspberry Pi it is going to be highly recommended that you use opto-couplers to interface between the Pi and the remote so that you can maintain a safe isolation. Beyond even safety there is the additional concern that if you did try to direct tie the GNDs between the remote and the PI it is possible that the A/C could fail to function properly - even more reason to think about using opto-couplers to control the button functions.

For the sake of further discussion here lets say that you have determined that the common (yellow lines) of the remote is indeed the GND and the other side of the paired switch finger pairs is found to be sitting at a positive voltage above GND when the contact fingers are not connected. The following diagram shows how to kludge in the opto-coupler to the remote key pad for one switch override function. The shown part number is one that I have used as it is a very efficient opto coupler that will fully turn on the output NPN transistor with as little as 1mA drive from the GPIO of the Pi microcontroller.

[image]

If the common buttons connection (yellow lines) happens to be the VDD of the remote and the blue line side of the button fingers sits at a lower voltage when the button fingers are not connected then you will want to swap around the NPN transistor Collector (pin 4) and the Emitter (pin 3) connections into the circuit.

In any case as shown an high level programmed onto the Pi GPIO will activate the NPN transistor to provide a short across the associated button finger contacts. It will likely be necessary to keep the Pi GPIO active for a period of 50msec or even 100msec to ensure the remote registers the signalling. The controller in the remote most likely has a switch debounce filter built in that has requires this length of active press time.

Comment: Amazing. I'm going to follow your advice and start by learning how to measure the voltages to identify the common connection.

Comment: Using a multimeter, the red V cable on the top contact and the black COM cable touching the bottom common contacts, I get a reading of ~5v. Does that indicate that the common connection is ground?

Comment: @user3758291 - The measurement that you made is a strong indication that the common contacts are ground but it is not a 100% indication. You would also need to check if this common connection is also the same connection as the return side of the power supply to the remote. The measurement that you made is however sufficient to let you know that you can connect opto couplers up as shown in the diagram. Was the assumption that there are just six user control functions on the remote a correct one?

Comment: Yes, you were correct. Six buttons. I will update my question.

Answer (score 0):

What is your goal here? For example, if your goal is to control the AC with the RasPi, I would first suggest finding out how the remote unit controls the AC. Options are RF signals, IR signals, and specialized RF such as Bluetooth or BLE.  What I would do is figure out what the control mechanism is, and then add that as part of the RasPi circuit.

If it is IR, you need to know what wavelength and modulation frequency are used.  A TV, for example, uses 940 nm with a 38 kHz modulation frequency. One way to test this is to spend a couple dollars to buy an IR receiver (NOT an IR-sensitive photosensor) device (e.g., www.adafruit.com search for item 157, $1.95). If it indicates reception of the AC remote, then your AC is running 940 nm/38 kHz. I did not see, in the photos, a Bluetooth, BLE, or WiFi antenna (a little zigzag trace), or anything with an FCC certification label, so I suspect IR. You can find IR receivers with other wavelengths and modulation frequencies at Digi-Key, Mouser, etc. You need to measure pulse widths to a few microseconds, and there are a number of standard protocols in use. If you discover that IR is the technique used, contact me here and we can discuss circuit design and software. For example, if it is IR, you need a 940 nm IR diode and the ability to create the same modulated waveforms as the buttons produce. This may be trickier on as RasPi than on an Arduino, or Cortek M-series chips, because the OS is going to make your life miserable.

For example, we are currently generating a 9 ms-long 38 kHz "start" signal. The signals become self-clocking, with a 528 us 38 kHz signal followed by 528 us of "silence" to mean 0, or 1056 us (2x528) to mean 1.  Each 2-byte command (b1,b2)nis encoded as 4 8-bit bytes
[b1, ~b1, b2, ~b2]

where the complement of the byte allows simple error checking. Pushing a button sends out a sequence of "button n pressed" messages, so even if a few are rejected due to noise, one will get through. Redundant messages are ignored until the next 9ms "start" signal.

Different remotes use different protocols, but they all resemble each other.  Example, another protocol sends 
[b1, b2, ~b1, ~b2]
It is insufficient to have a simple IR detector; the one I cited only responds to signals indicated by the 38 kHz carrier. This eliminates effects of room lighting, sunlight, steam irons, red-hot pokers, etc.

Comment: Thank you! I have rewritten my question to make it clear that this system actually uses a controller which is directly connected with an RJ11 jack. Due to this being an Australian system, there is not much information on protocols. I'm assuming your answer is only relevant in the case that there is a wireless connection.

Comment: So it is a wired remote, not a wireless?  In that case, just look at what signals are being sent over the RJ11 cable.  Unfortunately, this can be tricky, but you can find UART-in-software that might help with this.  Watching the pins with an Arduino or better still and M0 should give you a good idea what is going by.  But use a scope to look at the waveform; it might be RS-232, which means that there can be up to -18V on the line for a 0-bit.  This will fry an Arduino.  But you can use an RS-232 driver chip to reduce this to +5/0.